# How to avoid repeating maping operations for similar subscribers in Sping Reactor?

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have one publisher that emits strings and many subscribers that may use the same mapping function for creating models with different filters.

Publisher:

```
val publisher: Flux<String> = ...
```

Subscriber#1

```
val sub1 = publisher.map{veryExpensiveConverter.convert(it)}
                    .filter(it.metric<10)
```

Subscriber#2

```
val sub2 = publisher.map{veryExpensiveConverter.convert(it)}
                    .filter(it.metric>5)
```

Subscriber#3

```
val sub3 = sub2.map{cheapConverter.convert(it)}
                    .filter(it.metric>8)
```

Subscriber#4

```
val sub4 = sub3.map{yetAnotherConverter.convert(it)}
                    .filter(it.metric>80)
```

In the end I subscribe on all fluxes

```
Flux.merge(sub1, sub2, sub3, ..., subn)
     .map{//some logic for following data of subscribers}
     .subscribe()
```

The problem: *veryExpensiveConverter* is executed several time for the same published record for each subscriber.
The execution flow looks

```
Input1 -> veryExpensiveConverter -> filter1 -> output1
       -> veryExpensiveConverter -> filter2 -> output2
       -> veryExpensiveConverter -> cheapConverter -> filter3 -> output3
```

I would like too have

```
Input1 -> veryExpensiveConverter -> filter1 -> output1  
                                 -> filter2 -> output2
                                 -> cheapConverter -> filter3 -> output3
```

What's a pattern is the most suitable for avoiding execution of the same mapping for each subscriber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `.share()` at some level to ensure that every subscription to that shared part only trigger a single subscription above it.

You can also look into `.publish().xxx()` methods for more advanced auto-triggers (`.share()` will start its source as soon as the first subscription comes in).

Something like this:

```
val expensiveDoneOnce = publisher
    .map{veryExpensiveConverter.convert(it)}
    .publish()
    .refCount(2)
val sub1 = expensiveDoneOnce.filter(it.metric < 10)
val sub2 = expensiveDoneOnce.filter(it.metric > 5)
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, if the number of subscribers is not known upfront we cann do

publish() .... defining subscribers ... connect()

Comment: See also https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.multicasting.